# how to retrieve elements in raphael's set

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using raphael.s library to draw some shapes on canvas.I have combined different elements in set.I want to know that how to retrieve these elements using for loop on raphael's set.

Comment: Shows us the code you've tried to write so far.

Comment: [Set.forEach](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set.forEach) ?

Answer (score 3):

Jadkik94's suggestion is better -- using [set.forEach()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set.forEach) is more likely to be forward compatible with future versions of Raphael.